# QtGui & QtWidgets fail to find correct core on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, qtgui, qtwidgets

I've seen similar questions asked before, but none of the solutions worked for me. Some of the tools I need for my work unfortunately have a QT dependency.

I installed Qt using homebrew first. Setup paths and all that. I managed to build the tool, but when I run it i get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
Referenced from: /Users/kon/workspace/nexus/bin/./nxsbuild
Reason: Incompatible library version: nxsbuild requires version 5.13.0 or later, but QtGui provides version 5.7.0
```

My installed version is 5.13.1 and I can see that it is all correct. If i check the version of qmake for example, right thing shows up. I ran the otool on the executable and i get this, which is correct:

```
nxsbuild:
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.1)
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.1)
/System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

I tried looking for that version (5.7.0), but cannot find anything referring to it. I set env vars to point to the correct place, nothing helps. Here are the vars:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then I decided to try installing qt through python. I did that. I made a little test program, and i get very similar error message from it:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: QtWidgets.so requires version 5.13.0 or later, but QtWidgets provides version 5.7.0
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any ideas? Anything I should look at? Is there a way to get more info about my system? Please help, you guys are my only hope.

Edit: i also tried 'qtdiag'. I get the same error...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/bin/qtdiag
Reason: Incompatible library version: qtdiag requires version 5.13.0 or later, but QtWidgets provides version 5.7.0
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with Qt Installed from qt.io?

Comment: I just installed that, and it seems to work fine. I only used Qt Creator. It doesn't seem to have any effect on my system as whole though.

Comment: i loaded this project into Qt Creator and was able to build/run it successfully. i would still like to figure  out why command line doesn't work, but at least i can unblock myself.